# Export arguments names from jar in case of abstract methods

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, javadoc

I'm trying to package my Java library in a jar file containing only the .class files. The only public class in my library is an abstract class, say LibClass, with some of its methods declared as abstract and intended to be extended by the user of the library. My problem is that when I import the jar in a new project using Eclipse, for the non abstract methods the IDE is able to suggest me the names of the arguments of the functions, while for the abstract methods they are simply called arg0, arg1, arg2... (even if, of course, their types are correct).

This behavior doesn't happen and I'm able to see everything correctly if, instead of the jar, I include the library sources (but this is not an option for my final distribution).

How can I solve? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try including debugging information?

Comment: @DaveNewton sorry for the lame question but....how?

Comment: Don't recall for Eclipse; it's a compilation switch.

Comment: @DaveNewton thank you for your suggestion. Indeed, I was already compiling with it. Without using the -g I get not even the names of the arguments for the non-abstract functions...